# border-radius + overflow:hidden when animating with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyhgT/).

The orange bar is serving as a progress bar where the value under the circle is how high the progress bar should be.

Any idea why the `overflow:hidden;` is beeing disregarded and how do one solve this problem? Oblviously nothing should go outside the circle.

Also is there a better solution for this?

Comment: works fine on Chrome, but Firefox doesn't respect border-radius when filled... Which browser are you using?

Comment: Tested both in Chrome and Firefox, and the bug is there on both.

Comment: I fiddled with it in Firefox for a bit, and it looks like `position:absolute` takes the progress bar out of the container for the purposes of `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: the orange box overflow keeps flashing when I hover it (Chrome on Mac). I think it's the result of Jquery animation...

Answer (score 1):

Modified your fiddle a little bit. [Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyhgT/20/)

Modifications: 
Changed `.outerContainer` css to `display:block` from `display:table` and added`margin-top:30px` to `p` css

Check if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` don't appear to be playing nicely with `display: table/table-cell`. Removing the table stuff you had in there to vertically center the text fixes the problem. In Firefox, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the browser thing...

This is the CSS3 version...

```
.progressBar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ec6730;
    transition: height 1s;
}

.innerContainer:hover > .progressBar {
    height: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyhgT/2/

It no longer flashing 'cause browser handle the job (not js loop animation...). But still it shows the edge on animation finish!!! This could be the browser things... Could be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to jQuery or any javascript. In fact, if you delete all your javascript and manipulate the height of your .progressBar using css on li:hover, you will notice the bug anyway.

It appears to be a browser issue as reported on: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218

As a workaround try adding an imperceptible css transform to the mask element:

```
.outerContainer {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `.outerContainer` class and it works just fine!

```
.outerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 96px;
    width: 96px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;

  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the level class inside the outerContainer div and style the span inside the level class to be relatively positioned. In the JavaScript, to calculate the level, divide by 10 instead of 100 for the perfect circular hover effect.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhHYV/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <p>Circle 3</p>
        <span class="progressBar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="level"><span>75</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: blue;
}

#circles {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.outerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 96px;
    width: 96px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.innerContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    color: #000;
    width: 96px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.progressBar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ec6730;
}

.level span{
    position:relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#circles li").hover(function(){
        var thisElement = $(this);
        var level = $(this).find(".level").text();
        var elementHeight = $(this).find(".outerContainer").height();       
        level = (level/10)*elementHeight;

        $(thisElement).find(".progressBar").stop().animate({
            height: level
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        var thisElement = $(this);

        $(".progressBar").stop().animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: table` doesn't work that good with CSS positioning;

you should avoid using that, and find some other way to vertically center your labels.

If your circles have a known height, like your code seems to indicate (`height:96px` ecc), then just use a fixed top position for an `absolute`ly positioned `<p>` element:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyhgT/5/

Note that you don't even need jQuery for this, it is all achievable with just CSS3 (unless you are targeting old browsers)